# Create service layer with mocked data from LINQ DataContext

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-4, mocking

I'm using `LINQ-to-SQL` with ASP.NET MVC 4, and as of this moment I have a repository layer which contacts a real database. This is not very good when I want to unit test.

Also there should never be a logic in the repository layer, so this is why I want to mock the `LINQ DataContext` so I can create a service layer that talks either to the mock `DataContext` or to the real `DataContext`.

I see that my LINQ DataContext class inherits `DataContext`, but there is no interface, so I can't really mock that. I also see that DataContext uses `Table<>` class and there exists an interface `ITable`, so I probably could mock that. Also my `LINQ DataContext` is a partial class, so maybe I could manipulate that in some kind of way?

**When I google this, all articles are from 2008 and are outdated.
Can anyone guide me in the right appropriate direction?**

Here is an example of what I want to do. I will have seperate service class for each controller.

```
public class MyServiceClass
{
    IDataContext _context;

    // Constructors with dependency injection

    public MyServiceClass()
    {
        _context = new MyRealDataContext();
    }

    public MyServiceClass(IDataContext ctx)
    {
        _context = ctx;
    }

    // Service functions

    public IEnumerable<ModelClass> GetAll()
    {
        return _context.ModelClass;
    }

    public ModelClass GetOne(int id)
    {
        return _context.Where(s => s.ID == id).SingleOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although Linq-to-Sql is still supported in .NET 4+, it has been pushed back in favor of Entity Framework. That's probably why you're finding mostly older articles.

Anyway the best way to go is to write your own DataAccess layer-interface, used through your application. You then can have an implementation of that interface that uses your linq-to-sql for production and a mocked implementation for your unit tests.

Use dependency injection to instantiate the actual implementation class.

For creating a mock implementation you do it either manually (Creating a class in your test project that implements the IDataContext interface but returns hard-coded data) or use one of the mocking frameworks around there.

I have not used every one of them but [moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) was quite nice. Microsoft has now also their framework in Visual Studio 2012 called [Fakes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx), worth looking at.

Example of using moq

```
var expectedResultList = new List<ModelClass>(){ ... };
var mockDataContext = new Mock<IDataContext>();
mock.Setup(c => c.GetAll()).Returns(expectedResultList);

MyServiceClass service = new MyServiceClass(mockDataContext.Object);
var list = service.GetAll();
Assert.AreEqual(expectedResultList, list);
```

In this code you set up your mock object so that it will return your expected list when the GetAll method is called.
This way you can easily test your business logic based on different returns from your data access.

Example of IDataContext

```
public interface IDataContext<T>
{
   IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
   T GetById(int id);
   int Save(T model);
}

public class LinqToSqlDataContext<T> : IDataContext<T>
{
    private DataContext context = new DataContext();

    public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
         // query datacontext and return enumerable
    } 

    public T GetById(int id)
    {
         // query datacontext and return object
    }

    public int Save(T model)
    {
        // save object in datacontext
    }
}

public class MyFirstServiceClass
{
     private IDataContext<MyClass> context;
     public MyFirstServiceClass(IDataContext<MyClass> ctx)
     {
        this.context = ctx;
     }
     ....
}
public class MySecondServiceClass
{
     private IDataContext<MySecondClass> context;
     public MyFirstServiceClass(IDataContext<MySecondClass> ctx)
     {
        this.context = ctx;
     }
     ....
}
```

Comment: This is a large project I'm taking over and it's not optional to switch to EF. But in regard to LINQ, do you have an example for me?

Comment: Well, it's pretty much what you already have in your code. Your service class will work against your IDataContext interface. In production you will use an IDataContext implementation against your liq-to-sql, in Unit tests you can use a mocked implementation.

Comment: Just make sure your IDataContext does NOT expose any linq-to-sql specific classes

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure HOW to mock the DataContext. If you could help me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I updated my answer with an example, using moq as mocking framework.

Comment: Thank you for this. But how does IDataContext look like?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you already had this sorted out. In general, your IDataContext should expose generic methods that can be executed against your data storage. They should return lists and objects of your model classes. You should also provide methods to add/update/delete etc... pretty much everything you would do with your linq-to-sql datacontext.

Comment: Excellent, but this is not QUITE what I want. I want to have seperate services for each controller. This service in my code sample here above is an example one. There would be many more. This solution you suggest is to have one service for ALL mocks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with different services. I suppose each service handles a specific object type. There is no problem in creating multiple services the same way. You may even come up with a generic data access interface that can be re-used in different services `IDataAccess<T>` containing generic methods like `IEnumerable<T> GetAll()`. And then pass in that type in your constructor `public MyService(IDataAccess<MyClass> da)`

Comment: Ok, almost. However each service should be able to access many tables. For that I created a generic repository pattern like you said above, IDataAccess<MyClass> that contains a Dictionary<Type, object> with GetRepository<T>() capability, to return a repository (either a mock one or real). Thank you for your help, I will mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: Yes, you're in the right direction. Usually you may find this in implementations of a Unit Of Work, where the unit allows you to access multiple repositories and then commit/rollback all changes done. there are many examples on the web of how to implement this, most focused on Entity Framework but easily to be changed to Linq-to-Sql.